# Does jquery DataTables support responsive behavior in nested tables?

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I'm using the jQuery [DataTables plugin](https://datatables.net) on an ASP.NET app. The rows of the outer table are expandable to reveal a nested inner table under each row. Both tables must be responsive by removing columns as the screen shrinks.

The problem is that the inner table does not exhibit the responsive behavior. No matter how small the screen gets the inner table will not drop any columns. The outer table's responsive behavior works fine.

(Note: if you want to skip directly to some code that shows the issue, [check out this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a8a2q1u0/)).

Here is the outer table with all columns showing:

[image]

Here is the same view with one of the rows expanded:

[image]

Here is the outer table on a very small screen. You can see the last two columns have been dropped and no horizontal scrollbars are showing (everything working great so far):

[image]

Here is the same thing but with one of the rows expanded. You can see that all of the inner table's columns are showing and the horizontal scrollbars are needed to see them all (this is the problem):

[image]

Does this plugin simply not support responsive behaviors on nested tables or am I doing something wrong?

Below is the code, which has been adapted from an example on the DataTables website. Also, [here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a8a2q1u0/) with the same code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.0/css/dataTables.responsive.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.0/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>

    <body>
        <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="details-control">+</td>
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>$380,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="details-control">+</td>
                    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>$$170,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="details-control">+</td>
                    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                    <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>$86,000</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <script>
            /* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
            function format() {
                return '<table id="inner" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
                    '<thead><tr><th>Subgrid 1</th><th>Subgrid 2</th><th>Subgrid 3</th><th>Subgrid 4</th></tr></thead>' +
                    '<tbody>'+
                    '<tr>'+
                        '<td>Some data</td>'+
                        '<td>Some more data here</td>'+
                        '<td>Some really loooonnggg data in this column</td>'+
                        '<td>Yet more data</td>'+
                    '</tr>'
                    '</tbody>'+
                '</table>';
            }

            var options = {
                responsive: {
                    details: false
                },
                paging: false,
                lengthChange: false,
                filtering: false,
                info: false,
                searching: false
            };

            $(document).ready(function() {
                var table = $('#example').DataTable(options);

                $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
                    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                    var row = table.row( tr );

                    if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
                        // This row is already open - close it
                        row.child.hide();
                        tr.removeClass('shown');
                    }
                    else {
                        // Open this row
                        row.child(format()).show();
                        $('#inner').DataTable(options);

                        tr.addClass('shown');
                    }
                } );
            } );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900392/jquery-datatables-not-working-with-nested-tables) but it did not seem to answer the question.

Comment: Hi, were you able to find a solution to this?